# How execute with parameters python script in WLS2 from C# under Windows 10

Tags: python, c#, machine-learning, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have big project with C# and WinForms on Windows 10. I want to run from this program python script with ML libraries. Unfortunately i have some problems with work ML in native on Windows and want use WLS2 with Linux environment. It's real? How I should execute python script under WLS2 from C# under Windows10? Can it have access to MS SQL local server under Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can totally use WSL for your development. Your best option would be to use VS Code with remote extension for WSL. See the [doumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode).
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but question how i should and better do it. I should run bash.exe from C#? Or cmd.exe, or use something else. How i can execute python script that get data from my windows machine with MS SQL?

Comment: You can run wsl to get to wsl bash then call your python script if you want to do this within your code. For database I suggest you run your database on Docker and mount your volume to either your windows or WSL filesystem. If not you need to use IP address of your windows machine if you want to access any service running on windows from within WSL. Look at the [documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)